# Viewing the system.log.0.gz under /private/var/log in macOS

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, logs, apple

Am trying to view the contents of a system log -system.log.0 ,system.log.2 using macOS terminal .The logs are located under /private/var/log (macOS)

I have tried zcat,gunzip etc.but with no fruitful result.

```
gunzip -c system.log.0.gz 
gunzip: can't stat: system.log.0.gz (system.log.0.gz.gz): No such file or directory
```

What would be the suitable way to merge system.log.N into a *.log file and view them in terminal

Comment: What is the result of `ls  /private/var/log` ?

Comment: its system.log and system.log.0.....but when i perform gzip -l system.log.0,it says "not in gzip format"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment you do not have compressed files so there is no need to use `gunzip`. To view the file you can use commands like:

```
cat  /private/var/log/system.log.0
```

or

```
more /private/var/log/system.log.0
```

or

```
less /private/var/log/system.log.0
```

Same for file `/private/var/log/system.log` and other log files

Comment: @swastibhushandeb, in such case feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer :)